# Are there arbitrarily long prime deserts?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the maximum number of consecutive composite numbers possible?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186564/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-consecutive-composite-numbers-possible)

Define a prime desert of length $k$ to be a sequence of numbers $n + 1, n + 2, ..., n + k $ such that $n + i$ is composite for $1 \le i \le k$.  So my question is given a positive integer $k$ is there a prime desert of length $k$?

Comment: Yes. The usual approach is to look at the numbers $(k+1)!+2,(k+1)!+3,\dots,(k+1)!+k,(k+1)!+(k+1)$.

Comment: A common name for this is [prime gap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap).

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/37363/

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the maximum number of consecutive composite numbers possible?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/186564/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-consecutive-composite-numbers-possible).  Also related are http://math.stackexchange.com/q/168103/ and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20001/how-many-consecutive-composite-integers-follow-k1  (This comment might be autodeleted if the question is closed, but the links remain on the right.)

Comment: And it is expected that every even $n$ is the length of a gap infinitely often.

Comment: @hardmath: I don't think you can refer to this as prime gap because there is no assumption that $n$ and $n+k+1$ are prime. Obviously this makes a difference because you can have a prime desert of any length, but this is not true of prime gaps (for example, you can't have an odd prime gap other than $1$).

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese: Yes, but prime gaps are maximal prime deserts (those which cannot be extended at either end).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes there is always such a prime desert. Consider $(k+1)! +1, (k+1)! +2,\ldots (k+1)! +(k+1).$ Then for $2 \leq i \leq k+1,$ we see that $(k+1)! +i$ is divisible by $i,$ but is strictly greater than $i,$ so can't be prime.

Answer (score 5):

Here's an alternative approach that uses some heavier machinery.

We know that, if $\pi(x)$ denotes the number of primes $\leq x$, then $\pi(x)$ grows at roughly the same rate as $\frac{x}{\ln x}$, in the sense that $\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{\pi(x)}{x/\ln (x)}=1$. (This statement is called [The Prime Number Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem).) Now, if the largest prime desert were of size $k$, then $\pi(x)\geq\frac{x}{k+1}$. But $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x/(k+1)}{x/\ln(x)}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\ln(x)}{k+1}=\infty$.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. It is a nice exercise to show that the numbers $k!+2,\dots, k!+k$ are all composite and thus this is a prime desert of length $k-1$ (so we can get arbitrarily long ones by letting $k$ be large enough). We can of course do better for how large the numbers are by for example starting with $k!-2$ and going down to $k! - k$. I do not know how small we can make the smallest number in order to get a desert of length $k$ though.